# Add Publisher Action to Quote page layout

Tags: quote, publisher-action

Hi I need to add a publisher action to the Quote page layout, in order to launch a custom Visualforce page. However as you can see on the [image: screenshot] I don't have the Buttons, Links, and actions section on my configuration to add it.

Anyone knows how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason it's because a Quote Object is always related to an **Opportunity** via a **master relationship**. It's a bit like Opportunity Product, you can't create a publisher action for that object too.

I'm not sure what's your business logic, but you might create your publisher action on your opportunity instead, and with some logic redirect you to the right Quote. 
Also instead of a publisher action, you could create a custom button that redirect you to your VF page, which you will have to enable for mobile.

Comment: but custom buttons, don't work on Salesforce1, only publisher actions (I think it is on the roadmap for the next release)?